# Angular 2 Service using Fetch and Promise

Tags: typescript, promise, angular, fetch

I'm running Angular 2 beta.

I'm trying to create an http service using fetch that implements promises.  Here's what I have so far:

HttpService.ts:

```
@Injectable()
export class HTTPService {

    save(url: string, jsonPayload: JsonPayload): any {

        window.fetch(url, {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                       "Accept": "application/json",
                       "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            body: jsonPayload 
        })
        .then(status)
        .then(json)
        .then((response: any) => {
           this.response = response;

           return Promise.resolve(this.response);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
           console.log(error.message);

           return error.message;
        });
    }
}
```

Here's the service-consuming class:

```
export class ConsumingComponent {
    constructor(private _httpService: HTTPService) {
               ...
    }

    getSampleStuff() {
        this._httpService
            .save("http:sample.com/sample/stuff", this.jsonPayload)
            .then(response => this.response = response);

        this.sampleStuffModel = this.response;
    }
}
```

My intention to call a web service asynchronously.
This is how I understand the technology:

- Initialize a Promise in the service
- Inject the service into the consuming class
- Add a ".then(...)" in the consuming class.  the callback results land here.

I tried to set a class member ("this.response") to the response ("response").

When I run this promise, the response is null or undefined.

I'm guessing that the implementation of the resolve function is the source of the problem.  Do I wrap the entire window.fetch() in a resolve()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Returned values don't bubble through all the chain when using promises.

```
window.fetch(...)
  .then(status) // only status function will have the response
  .then(json)
```

Maybe I'm wrong but `status` and `json` don't seem to be functions. What are you trying to do here?

Your service code lacks a return to work as expected (I also removed `status` and `json`):

```
@Injectable()
export class HTTPService {
    save(url: string, jsonPayload: JsonPayload): any {
        // if you don't return anything, how the consumer will know it's a promise?
        return window.fetch(url, {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json",
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            body: jsonPayload
        })
        // do you really need to store the response into the service?
        // .then((response: any) => {
        //    this.response = response;
        //    return Promise.resolve(this.response);
        // })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error.message);
            // if you return error.message here, the consumer won't know there is a problem
            // you need to rethrow the error so it can be catched by the consumer
            throw error;
        });
    }
}
```

`windows.fetch()` is already a promise, don't wrap it in a `resolve()`.

Comment: You're last sentence might be the answer I'm looking for.  Angular 2 reference has an overly simplified implementation of Services here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt4.html#async-services-and-promises  The example implements a Promise, but the example doesn't use a web service as an example.  It led me to believe that I needed to implement a Promise.  Because fetch API already delivers a promise, there's no need for me to implement another one!!  I'll take your suggestion and not store the response in the service, too.  Thanks, again!

Comment: @LargeDachshund Keep in mind `fetch()` doesn't work on all browsers yet.

Comment: ShanShan, Thanks for the heads up.  So, you suggest using "http" that's built-into Angular 2?

Comment: @LargeDachshund I'm not familiar with Angular2 (only used v1) but it's better I think. `Http` is supposed to work an any browser plus it returns an Observable, it seems much more interesting than promises in Angular2 environment. A nice read about it: http://chariotsolutions.com/blog/post/angular2-observables-http-separating-services-components/